# See which page loads mine in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page that people load in an iframe (its like a widget they can put on their pages) and I want to see which pages are loading it... is this possible?

Comment: Why not track it through the url? yoursite.com/?iframe=url. This is what google does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not reliably possible due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

(You would have to read the value of [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent).[`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), which is [not possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).)

Comment: Is there any way to access a referrer or window.opener from the iframe that might be helpful?

Comment: @jfriend00 `document.referrer` is an empty string, `window.opener` is `null` for an IFRAME.

Comment: Just wondering as I was on a mobile phone and couldn't test it out myself.